# Query for counting items under parent category from a different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have stockcards and stockcategories table.

I want to display categories and show how many stockcards is openned under this category.

```
SELECT a.stockCatID, a.stockCatName, f.nProductsInside 
FROM stockcategories a 
LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(b.stockID) AS nProductsInside 
            FROM stockcards b 
        ) 
        f ON a.stockCatID = f.stockCatID
```

Well it returns `#1054 - Unknown column 'f.stockCatID' in 'on clause'`  Obviously I am making a mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.stockCatID, a.stockCatName, COUNT(b.stockID) as nProductsInside 
FROM stockcategories a 
LEFT JOIN stockcards b ON a.stockCatID = b.stockCatID 
group by a.stockCatID
```

You could probably do this too (unverified) ni order to stick with your query

```
SELECT a.stockCatID, a.stockCatName, f.nProductsInside 
FROM stockcategories a 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(b.stockID) AS nProductsInside, stockCatID
    FROM stockcards b 
) 
f ON a.stockCatID = f.stockCatID
```

Comment: second query was returned null for nProductInside but first one did the job. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try with something like:

```
SELECT a.stockCatID, a.stockCatName, COUNT(b.stockID) AS nProductsInside
FROM stockcategories a 
LEFT JOIN stockcards b ON a.stockCatID = b.stockCatID
GROUP BY a.id
```

where `a.id` is the primary key in the `stockcategories` table

Answer (score 0):

f is an alias for the result of SELECT COUNT(b.stockID)...
so f has no collumn